# for loop: running a function for each element in a list, determining a range of 7 days

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two lists, one with dates (`list_dates`) in the format mm/dd/yyyy and another list (`my_list`) with strings.
Example:

```
my_list=['my_string1', 'my_string2', 'my_string3']
list_dates=['11/20/2020','12/12/2019','07/12/2019']
```

I would need to run a function for all the items in `my_list` in a range of 7 days from its start_date, specifically:

- three days before its start_date;
- three days after  its start_date.

In the example:

- 'my_string1' has `start_date= 11/20/2020`
- 'my_string2' has `start_date= 12/12/2019`
- 'my_string3' has `start_date= 07/12/2019`

The structure of code that I would need should be:

- select the first item in `my_list`;
- select its `start_date` in `list_dates`;
- calculate the week range as follows: take `start_date` as `x` and calculate `x+3` and `x-3`. This will give its week range;
- run a function `f`, where `start=start_date` and `end=start`;
- collect results;
- then run the function f where `start=start_date - 1` and `end=start`;
- collect results;
  ...
- run the function `f` where `start=start_date-7` and `end=start`;
- collect results;
- select the second item in `my_list`
- select its `start_date` in `list_dates`;
- calculate the week range as follows: take `start_date` as `x` and calculate `x+3` and `x-3`. This will give its week range;
- run a function `f`, where `start=start_date` and `end=start`;
- collect results;
- then run the function `f` where `start=start_date - 1` and `end=start`;
- collect results;
  ...
- run the function *f* where `start=start_date-7` and `end=start`;
- collect results
  ... and repeat per all the elements in the list.

I tried to do it as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_range = 3

for i in my:_list: 
    for t in list_dates:
        t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
        before_dates = [ t - timedelta(i) for i in range(1,date_range+1)]
        after_dates =  [ t  + timedelta(i) for i in range(1,date_range+1)]   
        
        start=t
        end=start

    f(start, end, i)
```

but the loop does not work as I would expect, i.e. it does not do what I described in the bullets above.

Comment: please be a bit more concise, show your lists, show your function `fun` (resp. `fun1`). what is in the iterable object `test` ? how can you go through the items of `my_list` if its only dummy strings? Provide a minimal working example please

Comment: where is `start_date and  end_date` variable in your code?

Comment: I updated the question showing all the steps. I hope it can be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this what you are looking for? This is your code but chooses the full seven day range for each `my_list` entry and its corresponding date from `list_dates` as its central date (I added the function `fun` just to print for clarification):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_range = 3

my_list=['my_string1', 'my_string2', 'my_string3']
list_dates=['11/20/2020','12/12/2019','07/12/2019']

def fun(start_date, end_date, my_string):
    print(start_date, end_date, my_string)
    return

for i in range(len(my_list)): 
    print(my_list[i])
    #for t in list_dates:
    t = list_dates[i] # assume my_list and list_dates always correspond index-wise
    start_date = t
    end_date = t
    t = datetime.strptime(t, '%m/%d/%Y')
    #before_dates = [ t - timedelta(i) for i in range(date_range, 0, -1)]
    #after_dates =  [ t  + timedelta(i) for i in range(1, date_range+1)]
    ba_dates = [ t - timedelta(i) for i in range(date_range, -date_range-1, -1)]

    for isd in range(len(ba_dates)):
        #print(ba_dates[isd])
        #print(ba_dates[isd].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
        fun(ba_dates[isd].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), ba_dates[isd].strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), my_list[i])
```

for an output of

```
my_string1
2020/11/17 2020/11/17 my_string1
2020/11/18 2020/11/18 my_string1
2020/11/19 2020/11/19 my_string1
2020/11/20 2020/11/20 my_string1
2020/11/21 2020/11/21 my_string1
2020/11/22 2020/11/22 my_string1
2020/11/23 2020/11/23 my_string1
my_string2
2019/12/09 2019/12/09 my_string2
2019/12/10 2019/12/10 my_string2
2019/12/11 2019/12/11 my_string2
2019/12/12 2019/12/12 my_string2
2019/12/13 2019/12/13 my_string2
2019/12/14 2019/12/14 my_string2
2019/12/15 2019/12/15 my_string2
my_string3
2019/07/09 2019/07/09 my_string3
2019/07/10 2019/07/10 my_string3
2019/07/11 2019/07/11 my_string3
2019/07/12 2019/07/12 my_string3
2019/07/13 2019/07/13 my_string3
2019/07/14 2019/07/14 my_string3
2019/07/15 2019/07/15 my_string3
```

Comment: Hi Grimm yes, it is. But I am getting some issues with datetime. In my function I should would need to determine date range  as follows: f(s:'+start_date+',e:'+end_date+'&....') but when I run your code I get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str. How could I change the value (that should be in the form mm/dd/yyyy in the function?should it be converted into a string?

Comment: Hi I just repasted it, it works fine for me. At which line does the error occur? I have simplified it a bit, removed the tuple in the print (I was guessing the error might have occured there). It works for me even after clearing the Kernel.

Comment: I think the error using my function is that I am passing 2019-07-09T00:00:00 instead of 09/07/2020, could you please eventually include it in your code?

Comment: Yes, you did. Thanks a lot!